# WordPress: Creating new WP Users from Civi Contacts

Tags: wordpress, contacts, database, user

I've seen some example posts here for other CMS', but I haven't seen it explained for a WordPress environment. My situation is I have an Individual DB of 2,500 Contacts in Civi, and I want to turn them all into WP Users. I know I can convert Users into Contacts, but I want to do it the other way around.

Only thing I can think of is I would have to export the Contacts database as a CSV and then import them as Users either with a plugin or PHPmyAdmin. Isn't there some other way?

Comment: Christian Wach: This actually helps me with my issue, however, I just have a little concern. Is there a way to change the format of the WP user that is created in this process? I want the format to be first initial and last name.

Comment: Ali - since this isn't an answer to the original question please post it as a new question.  You can include a link to this one.

Comment: Related: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/wordpress/-/issues/82

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use my [CiviCRM WordPress Profile Sync](https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-wp-profile-sync/) plugin to do this, but I can't guarantee that it'll do them all in one go! You'd have to install the plugin, then set a PHP constant in the main plugin file (because it's a feature only really intended for developers at this stage) to enable this feature. Change line 22 to read:

`define( 'CIVICRM_WP_PROFILE_SYNC_BULK', true );`

EDIT: Better yet, add the above line to your `wp-config.php` file - then you won't have to re-edit the plugin after each update.

You will then be able to select contacts in CiviCRM and use the Bulk Operations menu to "Create WordPress Users from Contacts". I'd recommend limiting the number of contacts you migrate in each run. And that you backup before you try this.

Did I mention that you should backup before trying this? Oh, good!

Comment: Just a weeee bit, Christian. Thanks. I'll try this out.

And yes, I'll backup.....

Comment: Christian, I just tried your method. Basically I made myself an Individual contact in the Civi DB, then I went and selected "Create WordPress Users from Contacts" from the pulldown, took me to a page called Find Contacts. Clicked the Add button and was then taken to a master list of contacts. Went to Users and I couldn't find me. So something doesn't seem to be working. That is the process, isn't it?

Comment: UPDATE: I now can convert, however, I notice if I have any Civi contacts already as users, I get a DB Error message. The members without user accounts do convert though. So that's good.

Did notice a couple of other issues with the plugin, but I'm going to post those on the plugins page on the WP site. Thanks so far.

Comment: Ah, I didn't connect your username on wordpress.org to this thread! If you're getting errors, I'd recommend that you only select Contacts in CiviCRM that have no WordPress user yet. Though I appreciate the feedback. To repeat, this is only really intended for developers.

Comment: Adam: I've updated the plugin on the WordPress repo with a couple of minor changes to the bulk ops process. I'm not 100% sure if they will address the issues you encountered, but they will eliminate some possible causes.

Comment: Just to note that the line to change has moved to line 27 - caught me out, but should have read the text!

Comment: @MickKahn Try the version on GitHub if you want to try out the rewritten Civi-to-WP functionality. I'll release it on the WordPress plugin directory in due course, but you can try it now if you like https://github.com/christianwach/civicrm-wp-profile-sync

Comment: Version 0.2.7 did everything I needed once I'd changed the correct line so happy to wait for a formal release of 0.2.8 as I'm not clear what the changes are.