# Missing option to create WP User from contact

Tags: user-account

I'm not sure if I've lost the option because of a role or permission change. It used to be here:[image: Contact options menu]

and also in the bulk edit options for Contact search results.

I've made sure that "Anyone can register" is checked in the WP sites general settings. I am using CiviCRM WordPress Member Sync and CiviCRM WordPress Profile Sync (Christian Wach ftw)

I've also made sure that the contacts have email addresses, and current memberships (if relevant).

What am I missing? It used to be here.

Comment: How long ago do you remember seeing it? I'm asking because I remember coming across something like this a few months ago, where there was a smarty template for it but the functionality had become disconnected and I wasn't sure if it was on purpose or not. I can't remember if it was exactly this but it rings a bell. It was drupal but the template didn't care about CMS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a duplicate of this post [WordPress: Creating new WP Users from Civi Contacts](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9092/wordpress-creating-new-wp-users-from-civi-contacts)

On line 22 set it to true https://github.com/christianwach/civicrm-wp-profile-sync/blob/master/civicrm-wp-profile-sync.php#L22

`define( 'CIVICRM_WP_PROFILE_SYNC_BULK', true );`

The confusion is that you need to do a search action from either Advanced Search or Search Builder, not the actions button in the contact summary screen.

[image]

Comment: This `define` code can be added to your "wp-config.php" file so your changes aren't overwritten when the plugin is updated.